# Run cgi application locally with the owner's permissions

Tags: php, apache, cgi

As the title suggests, I am trying to execute a binary though cgi from the shell locally.
The problem is that the binary performs some privileged operations and so it has to run as the file's owner. 
The binary is executable for all users and it does run as the owner when it is called through the web interface

I have tried to set some of the environmental variables of php-cgi but i couldn't make it work, it just returned the executable's source:

> REDIRECT_STATUS=200 REQUEST_METHOD=GET SCRIPT_FILENAME=/path/to/cgi-bin/binary SCRIPT_NAME=/f/cgi-bin/binary PATH_INFO=/ SERVER_NAME=server SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1 QUERY_STRING="args" REQUEST_URI=/f/cgi-bin/binary HTTP_HOST=host /usr/bin/php-cgi

Is there any way to achieve that? (I am not root/sudoer)

Comment: what do you mean it has to run as the file's owner? Maybe you want to run it as the webserver user? what if you `su - www-data` ?

Comment: For example if all the cgi binary did is to execute a given command by the user, when you execute "id" through the web server you would get the owner of the file. If you run it locally, you will get the user that currently runs the binary. What i want, is to run it locally but run it with the permissions of the owner. (I have checked the executable and it doesn't have the suid, so the permissions are probably settled by php-cgi)